# Linux Bluetooth API Function Locations

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth, bluez

I have Bluez installed and the daemon is up. I am trying to write a very simple program to make sure everything is working. I am referring to the documentation at [index : bluez.git](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/).

My program is simple:

```
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    StartDiscovery();
}
```

However, when I compile I get this issue:

> ```
> $: g++ read_write.cpp -o read_write -I/usr/include/bluetooth -lbluetooth
> read_write.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
> read_write.cpp:11:20: error: ‘StartDiscovery’ was not declared in this scope
>      StartDiscovery();
> ```

Where are all the functions mentioned in the bluez docs actually at? Are there header files somewhere other than /usr/include/bluetooth that I need to reference?

Comment: According to [GitHub | pauloborges | bluez](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/profiles/cups/main.c), it looks like `StartDiscovery` is a d-bus message parameter, not a function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to access functionality provided by BlueZ.

1. Using D-Bus API (most common)
2. Using HCI socket
3. Using Management socket interface

   - All the API documentation in Bluez tree is about using D-Bus interfaces.
   - For using HCI socket you don't need to run Bluetooth daemon in user space. You can directly communicate with Kernel using AF_BLUETOOTH socket and request for HCI inquiry (for scanning). But this is not recommended as Bluez developers moved to management socket interface.
   - Management sockets are similar to HCI sockets which is implemented in kernel space, but in more generic or one way to access the controller. In HCI socket any number of user space application can asynchronously control the Bluetooth controller/Adapter. You can find more information here: http://www.bluez.org/the-management-interface/
   - bluetoothd daemon internally uses management socket to achieve all the tasks mentioned in doc/API and exports the results/API in D-Bus, thus by hiding all the internals of management socket. Yes, still you can directly use management socket to communicate with Linux Kernel.

Using HCI socket: https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html
**Using DBUS:**

```
/*
 * bluez_adapter_scan.c - Scan for bluetooth devices
 *  - This example scans for new devices after powering the adapter, if any devices
 *    appeared in /org/hciX/dev_XX_YY_ZZ_AA_BB_CC, it is monitered using "InterfaceAdded"
 *    signal and all the properties of the device is printed
 *  - Scanning continues to run until any device is disappered, this happens after 180 seconds
 *    automatically if the device is not used.
 * gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 gio-2.0` -Wall -Wextra -o ./bin/bluez_adapter_scan ./bluez_adapter_scan.c `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 gio-2.0`
 */
#include <glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

GDBusConnection *con;
static void bluez_property_value(const gchar *key, GVariant *value)
{
    const gchar *type = g_variant_get_type_string(value);

    g_print("\t%s : ", key);
    switch(*type) {
        case 'o':
        case 's':
            g_print("%s\n", g_variant_get_string(value, NULL));
            break;
        case 'b':
            g_print("%d\n", g_variant_get_boolean(value));
            break;
        case 'u':
            g_print("%d\n", g_variant_get_uint32(value));
            break;
        case 'a':
        /* TODO Handling only 'as', but not array of dicts */
            if(g_strcmp0(type, "as"))
                break;
            g_print("\n");
            const gchar *uuid;
            GVariantIter i;
            g_variant_iter_init(&i, value);
            while(g_variant_iter_next(&i, "s", &uuid))
                g_print("\t\t%s\n", uuid);
            break;
        default:
            g_print("Other\n");
            break;
    }
}

static void bluez_device_appeared(GDBusConnection *sig,
                const gchar *sender_name,
                const gchar *object_path,
                const gchar *interface,
                const gchar *signal_name,
                GVariant *parameters,
                gpointer user_data)
{
    (void)sig;
    (void)sender_name;
    (void)object_path;
    (void)interface;
    (void)signal_name;
    (void)user_data;

    GVariantIter *interfaces;
    const char *object;
    const gchar *interface_name;
    GVariant *properties;

    g_variant_get(parameters, "(&oa{sa{sv}})", &object, &interfaces);
    while(g_variant_iter_next(interfaces, "{&s@a{sv}}", &interface_name, &properties)) {
        if(g_strstr_len(g_ascii_strdown(interface_name, -1), -1, "device")) {
            g_print("[ %s ]\n", object);
            const gchar *property_name;
            GVariantIter i;
            GVariant *prop_val;
            g_variant_iter_init(&i, properties);
            while(g_variant_iter_next(&i, "{&sv}", &property_name, &prop_val))
                bluez_property_value(property_name, prop_val);
            g_variant_unref(prop_val);
        }
        g_variant_unref(properties);
    }
    return;
}

#define BT_ADDRESS_STRING_SIZE 18
static void bluez_device_disappeared(GDBusConnection *sig,
                const gchar *sender_name,
                const gchar *object_path,
                const gchar *interface,
                const gchar *signal_name,
                GVariant *parameters,
                gpointer user_data)
{
    (void)sig;
    (void)sender_name;
    (void)object_path;
    (void)interface;
    (void)signal_name;

    GVariantIter *interfaces;
    const char *object;
    const gchar *interface_name;
    char address[BT_ADDRESS_STRING_SIZE] = {'\0'};

    g_variant_get(parameters, "(&oas)", &object, &interfaces);
    while(g_variant_iter_next(interfaces, "s", &interface_name)) {
        if(g_strstr_len(g_ascii_strdown(interface_name, -1), -1, "device")) {
            int i;
            char *tmp = g_strstr_len(object, -1, "dev_") + 4;

            for(i = 0; *tmp != '\0'; i++, tmp++) {
                if(*tmp == '_') {
                    address[i] = ':';
                    continue;
                }
                address[i] = *tmp;
            }
            g_print("\nDevice %s removed\n", address);
            g_main_loop_quit((GMainLoop *)user_data);
        }
    }
    return;
}

static void bluez_signal_adapter_changed(GDBusConnection *conn,
                    const gchar *sender,
                    const gchar *path,
                    const gchar *interface,
                    const gchar *signal,
                    GVariant *params,
                    void *userdata)
{
    (void)conn;
    (void)sender;
    (void)path;
    (void)interface;
    (void)userdata;

    GVariantIter *properties = NULL;
    GVariantIter *unknown = NULL;
    const char *iface;
    const char *key;
    GVariant *value = NULL;
    const gchar *signature = g_variant_get_type_string(params);

    if(g_strcmp0(signature, "(sa{sv}as)") != 0) {
        g_print("Invalid signature for %s: %s != %s", signal, signature, "(sa{sv}as)");
        goto done;
    }

    g_variant_get(params, "(&sa{sv}as)", &iface, &properties, &unknown);
    while(g_variant_iter_next(properties, "{&sv}", &key, &value)) {
        if(!g_strcmp0(key, "Powered")) {
            if(!g_variant_is_of_type(value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)) {
                g_print("Invalid argument type for %s: %s != %s", key,
                        g_variant_get_type_string(value), "b");
                goto done;
            }
            g_print("Adapter is Powered \"%s\"\n", g_variant_get_boolean(value) ? "on" : "off");
        }
        if(!g_strcmp0(key, "Discovering")) {
            if(!g_variant_is_of_type(value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)) {
                g_print("Invalid argument type for %s: %s != %s", key,
                        g_variant_get_type_string(value), "b");
                goto done;
            }
            g_print("Adapter scan \"%s\"\n", g_variant_get_boolean(value) ? "on" : "off");
        }
    }
done:
    if(properties != NULL)
        g_variant_iter_free(properties);
    if(value != NULL)
        g_variant_unref(value);
}

static int bluez_adapter_call_method(const char *method)
{
    GVariant *result;
    GError *error = NULL;

    result = g_dbus_connection_call_sync(con,
                         "org.bluez",
                    /* TODO Find the adapter path runtime */
                         "/org/bluez/hci0",
                         "org.bluez.Adapter1",
                         method,
                         NULL,
                         NULL,
                         G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                         -1,
                         NULL,
                         &error);
    if(error != NULL)
        return 1;

    g_variant_unref(result);
    return 0;
}

static int bluez_adapter_set_property(const char *prop, GVariant *value)
{
    GVariant *result;
    GError *error = NULL;

    result = g_dbus_connection_call_sync(con,
                         "org.bluez",
                         "/org/bluez/hci0",
                         "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                         "Set",
                         g_variant_new("(ssv)", "org.bluez.Adapter1", prop, value),
                         NULL,
                         G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                         -1,
                         NULL,
                         &error);
    if(error != NULL)
        return 1;

    g_variant_unref(result);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    GMainLoop *loop;
    int rc;
    guint prop_changed;
    guint iface_added;
    guint iface_removed;

    con = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, NULL);
    if(con == NULL) {
        g_print("Not able to get connection to system bus\n");
        return 1;
    }

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    prop_changed = g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(con,
                        "org.bluez",
                        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                        "PropertiesChanged",
                        NULL,
                        "org.bluez.Adapter1",
                        G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE,
                        bluez_signal_adapter_changed,
                        NULL,
                        NULL);

    iface_added = g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(con,
                            "org.bluez",
                            "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager",
                            "InterfacesAdded",
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE,
                            bluez_device_appeared,
                            loop,
                            NULL);

    iface_removed = g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(con,
                            "org.bluez",
                            "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager",
                            "InterfacesRemoved",
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE,
                            bluez_device_disappeared,
                            loop,
                            NULL);

    rc = bluez_adapter_set_property("Powered", g_variant_new("b", TRUE));
    if(rc) {
        g_print("Not able to enable the adapter\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    rc = bluez_adapter_call_method("StartDiscovery");
    if(rc) {
        g_print("Not able to scan for new devices\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    g_main_loop_run(loop);
    rc = bluez_adapter_call_method("StopDiscovery");
    if(rc)
        g_print("Not able to stop scanning\n");
    g_usleep(100);

    rc = bluez_adapter_set_property("Powered", g_variant_new("b", FALSE));
    if(rc)
        g_print("Not able to disable the adapter\n");
fail:
    g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe(con, prop_changed);
    g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe(con, iface_added);
    g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe(con, iface_removed);
    g_object_unref(con);
    return 0;
}
```

This example is minimal to control the Bluetooth adapter property and start the scanning process using "StartDiscovery" method.

You can find more examples here: https://gist.github.com/parthitce
Documentation here: https://www.linumiz.com/category/blog/

EDIT:
Blog about StartDiscovery: https://www.linumiz.com/bluetooth-adapter-scan-for-new-devices-using-startdiscovery/